# How can I nest Velocity custom directives?

Tags: java, velocity

I've created 2 custom directives in Velocity one for internationalization and one for date formatting. They work great on their own, but now I'm to the point where I need to nest one in the other:

```
#msg('a_resource','TODAY',#date(1234567890900,'date')))!
```

However this doesn't work as I get the following exception.

```
org.apache.velocity.exception.ParseErrorException: Invalid arg #2 in directive #msg at dateTemplate[line 1, column 5]
```

How can I call the `#date` directive and pass it's value into the other one?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add double quotes around your directive call: `"`

```
#msg('a_resource','TODAY',"#date(1234567890900,'date')"))!
```

Velocity will evaluate anything in double quotes (like variables, methods, and as needed here: directives)

See: https://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/user-guide.html#stringliterals

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
#msg('a_resource','TODAY',"#date(1234567890900,'date')"))!
```